# como utilizar a interpolação do vue.js em um template do django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

O django utiliza uma ferramenta de sintaxe de template, chamada jinja2, ela permite a interpolação no documento html utilizando chaves duplas. Infelizmente, o vue.js usa a interpolação da mesma forma.

```
<p id="exemplo"> {{ message }}  </p>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#exemplo',
    data: { message: 'mensagem que deveria aparecer no paragrafo' }
  })
</script>
```

Em condições normais, apenas isso seria necessário para o funcionamento. Porém, o django reconhece como sua própria interpolação, não exibindo conteúdo algum.

Comment: Curiosidade: precisa servir um template Vue com o próprio Django? Por que?

Comment: Acho que a melhor resposta seria por diversão. Eu costumo usar uma stack baseada em node, e não é algo que me deixa muito animado em programar, então eu sempre procuro novas tecnologias para utilizar no tempo livre. Python se tornou minha linguagem preferida, e eu realmente adorei a experiência que tive com vue.

Answer (score 5):

Na configuração do Vue você tem a opção de definir novos delimitadores para o seu *template*, assim você pode informar algo que não conflite com o sistema de templates do Django.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  // ...
});
```

Assim, ao invés de utilizar `{{ message }}` basta utilizar `[[ message ]]`.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello World'
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<div id="app">[[ message ]]</div>
```